# PHPExcel Font Defaults Changing Column Dimensions

Tags: php, phpexcel

So I'm using [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/) to generate spreadsheets with data from a database. I have specific columns set to specific widths. When ever I try to use a default font for the entire spreadsheet though, these widths seem to be ignored and the sheet widens. Am i using this wrong? Where is [@Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker)?

```
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $phpColor = new PHPExcel_Style_Color();
    $phpColor->setRGB('051C48');  
    $objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setColor($phpColor);
    $objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setName('Gotham Book');
    $objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setSize(10);
    $activeSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $activeSheet->setShowGridlines(false);
    foreach(range('A','F') as $columnID){
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($columnID)->setAutoSize(false);
    }

    ///////////////////////////////// FIRST PHASE /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $activeSheet->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(22.71);
    $activeSheet->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(31.71);
    $activeSheet->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(9.71);
    $activeSheet->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(9.71);
    $activeSheet->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(11.85);
    $activeSheet->getColumnDimension('F')->setWidth(17.57);
```

**NO DEFAULT FONT SET:**
[image: No Default Font Screenshot]

**DEFAULT FONT SET:**
[image: Default Font Screenshot]

If you would like any additional information, just let me know. I realize those screenshots may not be the best method for showing whats happening. I can however just set a range for the cells, I was just hoping for cleaner code by setting a default value. Also if I'm being to specific and needy, just ignore me

```
$activeSheet->getStyle('A1:F1')->applyFromArray($firstRowStyle);
$activeSheet->getStyle('B2:B50')->applyFromArray($gothamBook10);
$activeSheet->getStyle('C2:C50')->applyFromArray($gothamBook10);
$activeSheet->getStyle('D2:D50')->applyFromArray($gothamBook10);
$activeSheet->getStyle('E2:E50')->applyFromArray($gothamBook10);
$activeSheet->getStyle('F2:F50')->applyFromArray($gothamBook10);
```